# Swift 3 - FTP Upload

Tags: ios, ftp, swift3

I have added the Rebekka touch framework to my Swift 3 project in order to upload files via FTP.

I have used the swift 3 conversion tool in xCode and I'm left with just one error

> Value of type 'NSMutableData' has no member 'count'

And here's where it occurs:

```
let bytes = self.inputData!.bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: self.inputData!.count)
```

Full Function:

```
override func streamEventEnd(_ aStream: Stream) -> (Bool, NSError?) {
    var offset = 0
    let bytes = self.inputData!.bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: self.inputData!.count)
    let totalBytes = CFIndex(self.inputData!.length)
    var parsedBytes = CFIndex(0)
    let entity = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFDictionary>?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    var resources = [ResourceItem]()
    repeat {
        parsedBytes = CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(nil, bytes.advancedBy(offset), totalBytes - offset, entity)
        if parsedBytes > 0 {
            let value = entity.pointee?.takeUnretainedValue()
            if let fptResource = value {
                resources.append(self.mapFTPResources(fptResource))
            }
            offset += parsedBytes
        }
    } while parsedBytes > 0
    self.resources = resources
    entity.deinitialize()
    return (true, nil)
}
```

Does anybody know the swift 3 equivalent of `self.inputData!.count` ?

Comment: what about `self.inputData!.length ?`

Comment: Try to use `.length` property of `Data`

Comment: I'm trying that now, I will update question if it works

Comment: Yep worked, added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I used .length to get this working, along with some other slight changes as below:

```
override func streamEventEnd(_ aStream: Stream) -> (Bool, NSError?) {
    var offset = 0
    let bytes = self.inputData!.bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: self.inputData!.count)
    let totalBytes = CFIndex(self.inputData!.length)
    var parsedBytes = CFIndex(0)
    let entity = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFDictionary>?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    var resources = [ResourceItem]()
    repeat {
        parsedBytes = CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(nil, bytes.advancedBy(offset), totalBytes - offset, entity)
        if parsedBytes > 0 {
            let value = entity.pointee?.takeUnretainedValue()
            if let fptResource = value {
                resources.append(self.mapFTPResources(fptResource))
            }
            offset += parsedBytes
        }
    } while parsedBytes > 0
    self.resources = resources
    entity.deinitialize()
    return (true, nil)
}
```

I then got some errors when tying to use Rebekka touch, the example usage didn't work so I modified slightly as below:

```
var configuration = SessionConfiguration()
            configuration.host = "ftp.somewebsite.co.uk"
            configuration.username = "username"
            configuration.password = "password"
             let URL = filename
                let path = "/"+currentJob.ReservationsID+".png"
                Session(configuration: configuration).upload(URL, path: path) {
                    (result, error) -> Void in
                    print("Upload file with result:\n\(result), error: \(error)\n\n")

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Swift3. 
I did the following changes in the source code of Rebekka framework, specifically, the file ResourceListOperation.swift. (Note: advanced(by:..), .length).

```
fileprivate var inputData: NSMutableData?
var resources: [ResourceItem]?

override func streamEventEnd(_ aStream: Stream) -> (Bool, NSError?) {
    var offset = 0
    let bytes = self.inputData!.bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: self.inputData!.length)
    let totalBytes = CFIndex(self.inputData!.length)
    var parsedBytes = CFIndex(0)
    let entity = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFDictionary>?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    var resources = [ResourceItem]()
    repeat {
        parsedBytes = CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(nil, bytes.advanced(by: offset), totalBytes - offset, entity)
        if parsedBytes > 0 {
            let value = entity.pointee?.takeUnretainedValue()
            if let fptResource = value {
                resources.append(self.mapFTPResources(fptResource))
            }
            offset += parsedBytes
        }
    } while parsedBytes > 0
    self.resources = resources
    entity.deinitialize()
    return (true, nil)
}
```

Here is what I used in my application to list the directory after importing RebekkaTouch framework:

```
    var configuration = SessionConfiguration()
    configuration.host = "<ip-address:followed-by-port>"
    configuration.username = "uname"
    configuration.password = "password"
    configuration.encoding = String.Encoding.utf8
    self.session = Session(configuration: configuration)
    self.session.list("/") {
        (resources, error) -> Void in
        print("List directory with result:\n\(String(describing: resources)), error: \(String(describing: error))\n\n")
    }
```